# Patch multiple person column to sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula, powerapps-collection

I'm trying to patch a multi-person column to a collection and then to Sharepoint from a combo box, but I can't get it right. I'm able to patch a single row. My issue now is how to patch multiple rows at once. This is what I have now:

```
ForAll(
        Filter(
                gal_NewBudget_4.AllItems,
        tog_NewBudget_isChanged_2.Value
        ) As NewUnitRows, 
        Patch(colAdminUnits,
        Defaults(colAdminUnits), {
            ID: NewUnitRows.ID,

            Title: NewUnitRows.txt_AdminUnits_Unit.Text,

            Department: NewUnitRows.txt_AdminUnits_Dept.Text,

            UnitHead: {
            '@odata.type': "#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedUser",
            Claims: "i:0#.f|membership|" & NewUnitRows.cmb_AdminUnits_UnitHead.Selected.DisplayName,
            Department: "",
            DisplayName: NewUnitRows.cmb_AdminUnits_UnitHead.Selected.DisplayName,
            Email: NewUnitRows.cmb_AdminUnits_UnitHead.Selected.DisplayName,
            JobTitle: "",
            Picture: ""},

            DepartmentHead: {
            '@odata.type': "#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedUser",
            Claims: "i:0#.f|membership|" & NewUnitRows.cmb_AdminUnits_DeptHead.Selected.DisplayName,
            Department: "",
            DisplayName: NewUnitRows.cmb_AdminUnits_DeptHead.Selected.DisplayName,
            Email: NewUnitRows.cmb_AdminUnits_DeptHead.Selected.DisplayName,
            JobTitle: "",
            Picture: ""},

            Members: ForAll(cmb_AdminUnits_PVInitiator.SelectedItems, Collect(colMem, {
            '@odata.type': "#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedUser",
            Claims: "i:0#.f|membership|" & ThisRecord.DisplayName,
            Department: "",
            DisplayName: ThisRecord.DisplayName,
            Email: ThisRecord.DisplayName,
            JobTitle: "",
            Picture: ""
        }))
        })
    );
```

My issue is with the members' column. I'm not exactly sure how to handle it. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: HI ,Here is a link about Patch A SharePoint Person Column With Multiple People In Power Apps for your reference :https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-patch-a-sharepoint-person-column-with-multiple-people-in-power#:~:text=In%20this%20blog%2C%20we%20are%20going%20to%20see,to%20%22Nagalingam%20Ravishankar%22%2C%20%22Ajith%20Shanmugam%22%20and%20%22Veeramani%20Subramani%22.